# How can I tell which query uses an index in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, index-tuning, mysql-8.0

I have investigated my indexes in MySQL using `performance_schema.table_io_waits_summary_by_index_usage` which has told me that one of my indexes is used in one database environment (Production EU) but not the other two (Production US and Sandbox). However I expected all of my environments to use the same indexes.

How can I find out which queries are using that index?

Ideally I'd like to log the SQL somewhere when the specific index is used. My application runs hundreds of different queries so running `EXPLAIN` on each of them is not an option unless there's some tool for automating that from the general log or something.

Comment: "*However I expected all of my environments to use the same indexes.*" - Do all of your environments have exactly the same data between them in all tables? If not, then all bets are off. "*My application runs hundreds of different queries so running EXPLAIN on each of them is not an option...*" - You'd probably only need the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for only one example query where the index is being used in one environment but not the other(s), to understand what's going on.

Comment: No, they don't but that doesn't change my question. I want to know what SQL is running using this index which I don't think should be used. It's on a fairly big table and so the cost of the additional index is non-trivial.

Comment: @J.D. the question I'm asking is how do I find a query that is using the index at all? I can't run `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` without a query to run it on.

Comment: "*how do I find a query that is using the index at all?*" - Well you know what table the index is on & the fields it encompasses, so you'd probably want to look at the code of your application to find some queries that use that table and filter on those fields, for example. It's a little bit of a backwards approach in this case, because usually as DBAs we're troubleshooting slow queries and therefore are already starting with said problematic query. There may be system objects that expose the query plans of recently executed queries too, but I'm not sure for MySQL. If I get a chance I'll look.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply not possible to say "this index is never used".

- The constants in a query are important in choosing which index to use.
- The index choice is dynamic -- picked for each query each time it is run.  I once found a query that used 6 different indexes over several days and with different constants fed into it.  (This agrees with the Comments already discussed.)
- Don't forget that important big Delete you run at the end of the month.  It used a particular index that is not used for anything else.

Why worry about extra indexes?  Sure they waste disk space and slightly slow down Inserts/Updates/Deletes.  Indexing should be approached from the other side -- "What are the best indexes for my queries."

Some tips:

- `INDEX(a)` is not needed if you also have `INDEX(a,b)`.  I have seen cases where having both indexes leads the Optimizer to use the smaller index even though `(a,b)` would be faster.
- Don't index a 'flag' by itself.  But having it as the first column in a 'composite' index may be useful.
- Use the queries to design the indexes that are likely to be useful:  [*Index Cookbook*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)
- Delete and Update techniques: https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig
- Use the slowlog to find the slow queries; worry about the *lack* of a proper index on such queries.
- `ANALYZE TABLE` (fast, non-invasive) will *sometimes* change the statistics enough for the Optimizer to pick a different index.  This does a simplified set of probes into the table to get a feel for the distribution of values.  That statistic is part of what is used to decide on which index to use.

Comment: I get that generally, but the cost of our database storage needs to come down and so I'm finding indexes that are not used - and by not used I mean that `count_star` is zero in `table_io_waits_summary_by_index_usage` after the database has been running for some minimum number of days, months or years. I'm confident this index is not required on 2 of the 3 environments and I'm wanting to understand why the query plan is choosing it on the last environment. There may be some data issue for example but without knowing the query that uses it, it's hard to start this understanding.

Comment: @mjaggard - I added to my first tip and added a new last tip.

Comment: Thanks but none of your tips or answer (except "Why worry about extra indexes?") address my question of "how can I find the relevant query in a complex system?"